# How can I handle user input in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm trying to test code that runs off user input in VS Code.

When I use 'prompt' I get:

```
ReferenceError: prompt is not defined
```

I googled that and found this page saying I need to use node.js - makes sense!

I tried the node.js example code here:

```
var readline = require('readline');

var rl = readline.createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  output: process.stdout
});

rl.question("What do you think of node.js? ", function(answer) {
  // TODO: Log the answer in a database
  console.log("Thank you for your valuable feedback:", answer);

  rl.close();
});
```

When I run it in VS Code I can see the output in the terminal asking for the input:

```
[Running] node "C:\Users\jon_d\AppData\Local\Temp\tempCodeRunnerFile.javascript"
What do you think of node.js?
```

But I can see anyway to input a value in VS Code? Someone mentioned I need to use an external terminal - but I can't find any info on how to do that on a PC only OSX? Can someone explain how i use cmd for this?

Cheers,
Jon

Answer (score 0):

Since Windows PCs don't have a real "terminal", a common solution is to use vscode with [WSL](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/wsl) (Windows Subsystem for Linux). This replicates the workspace of a linux machine in vscode - you have access to a real terminal (which is built into vscode) and this is where you would enter your user input.

I'm not sure if what you want to do is possible with only cmd/powershell, but since WSL is so common and convenient, I thought I'd put it out there.